# `import =` is not supported by @babel/plugin-transform-typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, babeljs, nrwl-nx

I'm using nx, and IntelliJ really wants to import `Firestore` like this:

```
import Firestore = firebase.firestore.Firestore;
```

I end up with the following error though when compiling:

> import = is not supported by @babel/plugin-transform-typescript
> Please consider using `import <moduleName> from '<moduleName>';` alongside Typescript's --allowSyntheticDefaultImports option.

I'm fairly new to the js ecosystem, so I'm not entirely sure of the best way to proceed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "IntelliJ really wants".  If you're writing typescript, the error message is telling you what the import should look like.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to structure it as a `import <moduleName> from '<moduleName>'`. How am I supposed to?

Comment: It's a limitation of Babel's TypeScript support, just as the error indicates.

Comment: @AluanHaddad right... how should I be importing it based on it's recommendation?

Comment: `const Firestore = firebase.firestore.Firestore; type Firestore = typeof Firestore;`

Comment: Had the same issue when using the official types of the monaco editor, I eventually removed the imports and refactored my code to use the full namespace as the type: ```markInvalidStatement(model: monaco.editor.ITextModel, markers: monaco.editor.IMarkerData[]) ```